# Can't upload to PyPI with twine ("invalid command")

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi, twine

I'm trying to upload my package to PyPI using twine.
I've followed the [official documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#upload-your-distributions) and I'm getting stopped at this step:
`twine upload dist/*`
I don't have errors on any previous steps, and I've been using python3 instead of python (so all previous steps have used python3 or pip3)

```
$ twine upload dist/*
Invalid command: upload

$ which twine
/usr/local/bin/twine

$ twine --version
Twine version 1.0.1

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Turns out I have a different twine installed, [this one](https://github.com/scelis/twine), causing the error. How can I remove the currently installed twine and install the correct PyPi Twine?

**Update 1**
I've removed the other version of twine. I ran `pip3 install twine` and it gave a lot of lines of Requirement already satisfied: `twine in /Users/.....` but if I run `twine --version` I get `-bash: twine: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have something else in your $PATH which matches `twine`, and so it might be using this instead of the PyPi Twine?

$PATH is searched from beginning to end, with the first matching executable being run. So directories at the beginning of $PATH take precedence over those that come later.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll take a look!

Comment: @singmotor you can try moving twine to the start of your $PATH to see if this fixes it

Comment: Ahhh looks like the twine I'm getting is this https://github.com/scelis/twine how can I overwrite that one with the pipit twine?

Comment: @singmotor you have to either reorder your $PATH so that the folder containing the PyPi Twine is above the "scelis" Twine, or you can remove the "scelis" folder from your $PATH altogether

Comment: @singmotor If you managed to get it working with my suggestion, please can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: ECH will do, sorry for the delay, but I haven't actually had time to try implementing this yet. I won't forget the question and will mark it as accepted once I've tried this!

Comment: I still haven't had luck. You've answered the first part of my question, but the second part "install the correct PyPi Twine" still eludes me. I ran pip3 install twine and it gave a lot of lines of `Requirement already satisfied: twine in /Users/.....` but if I run `twine --version` I get `-bash: twine: command not found`

Comment: I figured out the above. I needed to upload the python3 twine. So had to upgrade pip3 with `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and then twine with pip3 install twine. Then all worked!

Comment: @singmotor Glad you got it sorted!